# csh cannot be launched

Tags: bash, csh

After I log into our server with bash, I try to switch to csh, but it was stuck there. I wonder what is happening at csh startup?

I don't have .cshrc file. I'm pretty sure this is related to some settings specific to my account because another user can use csh without problem. I tried to delete my .bash_profile and .bashrc and copied them from the account mentioned above, but they didn't work.

update: Nov 25, 2014 15:31 PM

Thanks for all the comments, especially for mentioning 'csh -X'. First let me clarify a couple of things:

1. by 'stuck' I mean no shell prompt appears after I type `csh`
2. I checked `top` after `csh`, csh is in status 'S', so it's not looping infinitely
3. `csh` is indeed a symbolic link to `tcsh`
4. type 'x' or enter after 'csh' hangs doesn't change the situation

Here's what I got after type `csh -X`, any clue?

```
    [user@cluster ~]$ csh -X
    if ( 547 > 199 && `id -gn` == `id -un` ) then
    id -gn
    id -un
    umask 022
    endif
    if ( 1 ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    set promptchars=$#
    set prompt=[%n@%m %c]%#
    set autolist
    else
    endif
    if ( 1 ) then
    bindkey ^[[3~ delete-char
    endif
    bindkey ^R i-search-back
    set echo_style = both
    set histdup = erase
    set savehist = ( 1024 merge )
    if ( 1 ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    switch ( xterm )
    if ( 1 ) then
    set prompt=%{\033]0;%n@%m:%c\007%}[%n@%m %c]%#
    endif
    breaksw
    endif
    endif
    setenv MAIL /var/spool/mail/user
    if ( ! 0 ) then
    if ( -d /etc/profile.d ) then
    set nonomatch
    foreach i ( /etc/profile.d/*.csh )
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/apache-ant.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/apache-ant.csh
    setenv ANT_HOME /opt/rocks
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/colorls.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/colorls.csh
    if ( 0 ) then
    alias ll ls -l
    alias l. ls -d .*
    set COLORS=/etc/DIR_COLORS
    if ( 1 ) then
    if ( -e /etc/DIR_COLORS.xterm ) then
    if ( -e /etc/DIR_COLORS.256color ) then
    if ( `tput colors` == 256 ) then
    tput colors
    endif
    endif
    if ( -f ~/.dircolors ) set COLORS=~/.dircolors
    if ( -f ~/.dir_colors ) set COLORS=~/.dir_colors
    if ( 1 ) then
    if ( -f ~/.dircolors.xterm ) set COLORS=~/.dircolors.xterm
    if ( -f ~/.dir_colors.xterm ) set COLORS=~/.dir_colors.xterm
    endif
    if ( ! -e /etc/DIR_COLORS ) exit
    eval `dircolors -c /etc/DIR_COLORS`
    dircolors -c /etc/DIR_COLORS
    setenv LS_COLORS rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
    if ( rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36: ==  ) exit
    set color_none=`sed -n '/^COLOR.*none/Ip' < $COLORS`
    sed -n /^COLOR.*none/Ip
    if (  !=  ) then
    unset color_none
    finish:
    alias ll ls -l --color=auto
    alias l. ls -d .* --color=auto
    alias ls ls --color=auto
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/cvs.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/cvs.csh
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/eclipse.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/eclipse.csh
    setenv ECLIPSE_HOME /opt/eclipse
    set BIN=/opt/eclipse
    if ( -d /opt/eclipse ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/eclipse
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/ganglia-binaries.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/ganglia-binaries.csh
    set GANGLIA_HOME=/opt/ganglia
    set BIN=/opt/ganglia/bin
    set SBIN=/opt/ganglia/sbin
    if ( -d /opt/ganglia/bin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/ganglia/bin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    if ( -d /opt/ganglia/sbin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/ganglia/sbin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/glib2.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/glib2.csh
    setenv G_BROKEN_FILENAMES 1
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.csh
    setenv SSH_ASKPASS /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/java.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/java.csh
    setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/java/latest
    set BIN=/usr/java/latest/bin
    if ( -d /usr/java/latest/bin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /usr/java/latest/bin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/lang.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/lang.csh
    set sourced=0
    if ( 1 ) then
    set saved_lang=en_US.iso885915
    if ( -f /home/user/.i18n ) then
    setenv LANG en_US.iso885915
    unset saved_lang
    else
    if ( 0 == 1 ) then
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/less.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/less.csh
    if ( -x /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh ) then
    setenv LESSOPEN |/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/maven.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/maven.csh
    setenv MAVEN_HOME /opt/maven
    set BIN=/opt/maven/bin
    if ( -d /opt/maven/bin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/maven/bin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/modules.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/modules.csh
    if ( 1 ) then
    set modules_shell=tcsh
    else
    set exec_prefix=/usr/bin
    set prefix=
    set postfix=
    if ( 0 ) then
    set histchar = !
    endif
    if ( 1 ) then
    set prefix = set _prompt="$prompt";set prompt="";
    set postfix = set prompt="$_prompt";unset _prompt;
    endif
    if ( 0 ) then
    set postfix = set _exit=$status; set prompt="$_prompt";unset _prompt;; test 0 = $_exit;
    alias module set _prompt="$prompt";set prompt="";eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd tcsh !*`; set _exit=$status; set prompt="$_prompt";unset _prompt;; test 0 = $_exit;
    unset exec_prefix
    unset prefix
    unset postfix
    setenv MODULESHOME /usr/share/Modules
    if ( ! 1 ) then
    if ( ! 1 ) then
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/pdsh.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/pdsh.csh
    set PDSHROOT=/opt/pdsh
    set BIN=/opt/pdsh/bin
    if ( -d /opt/pdsh/bin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/pdsh/bin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/qt.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/qt.csh
    if ( 1 ) then
    exit
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/rocks-binaries.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/rocks-binaries.csh
    setenv ROCKS_ROOT /opt/rocks
    set BIN=/opt/rocks/bin
    set SBIN=/opt/rocks/bin
    if ( -d /opt/rocks/bin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/rocks/bin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    if ( -d /opt/rocks/bin ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/rocks/bin
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/rocks-devel.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/rocks-devel.csh
    setenv ROCKSROOT /opt/rocks/share/devel
    setenv ROLLSROOT /opt/rocks/share/devel/src/roll
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.csh
    if ( ! 0 ) then
    set _prompt=%{\033]0;%n@%m:%c\007%}[%n@%m %c]%#
    set prompt=
    eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd tcsh -s add rocks-openmpi`
    /usr/bin/modulecmd tcsh -s add rocks-openmpi
    set _exit=0
    set prompt=%{\033]0;%n@%m:%c\007%}[%n@%m %c]%#
    unset _prompt
    test 0 = 0
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/rocks-lang.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/rocks-lang.csh
    if ( 1 ) then
    if ( xterm == linux ) then
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/sge-binaries.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/sge-binaries.csh
    setenv SGE_ROOT /opt/gridengine
    setenv SGE_ARCH `$SGE_ROOT/util/arch`
    /opt/gridengine/util/arch
    set DEFAULTMANPATH = `$SGE_ROOT/util/arch -m`
    /opt/gridengine/util/arch -m
    set MANTYPE = `$SGE_ROOT/util/arch -mt`
    /opt/gridengine/util/arch -mt
    setenv SGE_CELL default
    setenv SGE_QMASTER_PORT 536
    setenv SGE_EXECD_PORT 537
    set BIN=/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64
    if ( -d /opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64 ) then
    echo /home/user/software/tophat-2.0.10.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/samtools-0.1.19:/home/user/software/bowtie2-2.2.1:/home/user/software/boost_1_55_0:/home/user/software/Mus_musculus:/home/user/software/bowtie-1.0.1:/home/user/software/FastQC:/home/user/software/bedtools2-2.19.1/bin:/home/user/software/cufflinks-2.2.0.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/bin:/home/user/software/STAR_2.3.0e.Linux_x86_64:/home/user/software/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8:/home/user/software/pysam-0.8.0:/home/user/software/CIRCexplorer-1.0.3:/home/user/software/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysam-0.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pysam/__init__.pyc':/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/user/bin
    /bin/grep -q /opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64
    if ( 0 != 0 ) then
    endif
    set shlib_path_name = `$SGE_ROOT/util/arch -lib`
    /opt/gridengine/util/arch -lib
    if ( `eval echo '$?'$shlib_path_name` ) then
    eval echo $?LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    echo 1
    set old_value = `eval echo '$'$shlib_path_name`
    eval echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    echo /opt/gridengine/lib/linux-x64:/opt/openmpi/lib
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/gridengine/lib/linux-x64:/opt/gridengine/lib/linux-x64:/opt/openmpi/lib
    else
    unset DEFAULTMANPATH MANTYPE shlib_path_name
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/sge-mpi.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/sge-mpi.csh
    setenv MPICH_PROCESS_GROUP no
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/ssh-key.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/ssh-key.csh
    /bin/bash /etc/profile.d/ssh-key.sh
    else
    endif
    end
    if ( -r /etc/profile.d/vim.csh ) then
    if ( 1 ) then
    source /etc/profile.d/vim.csh
    if ( -x /usr/bin/id ) then
    if ( `/usr/bin/id -u` > 200 ) then
    /usr/bin/id -u
    alias vi vim
    endif
    endif
    else
    endif
    end
    unset i nonomatch
    endif
    endif
```

Comment: Your bash startup scripts have nothing to do with csh starting (unless you erroneously source them from .profile or similar). Is that snippet supposed to show a lack of csh prompt? Does hitting `ctrl-c` get you back to the bash prompt?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you're "stuck"?

Comment: Thanks. `ctrl-c` does get me back to bash.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this execution log. I think it makes sense to compare it line by line with another one from a user who doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I compared the two and found only some PATH settings differ. Another weird thing I found is that after I run `csh -X` and `ctrl-c`, I have to type 'exit' rather than 'logout' to log off remote terminal because shell complains this is not login shell. It seems csh is indeed running but just don't show the prompt.

Comment: I don't understand your last statement about `logout`. You said before that `ctrl-c` gets you back to the bash, and the bash is your login shell on remote machine, right?

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability that your `csh` is symlinked to the `tcsh`, so please read the `tcsh` manual (the startup section) - there are other startup files, which the `tcsh` tries to load (not only the `.cshrc`).

Basically this hanging behavior might mean, that the shell is trying to access a machine, which is not accessible from your environment.

Comment: Or that you're doing *something* in your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` that's taking forever. Try `csh -X`; this will cause it to print commands before executing them.

Comment: just to extend the list of possible causes for hanging: your .cshrc is waiting for user input (without prompting for it!). So try just hitting the enter key, or typing something , just `x` and then hit the enter key and see what happens. `csh -X` is the best route, however. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - I like this hypothesis!